# how to show email suggestions from database with magicSuggest PHP

Tags: php, magicsuggest

I have a problem with the magicSuggest plugin. I trie to display all email addresses from my database with magicSuggest, but the output-list become empty.

from create_event.php

```
   <script>

   $('#ms-allowFreeEntries').magicSuggest({
      placeholder : "Select" , 
      data : "email.php" 
    });


   </script>
```

from email.php

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
include('includes/db.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
  $result = $db->query("select `email` from `users");

  $rows = array();
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);
  }

  echo json_encode($rows);
  $result->close();
  $db->close();

  ?>
```

picture from 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWXm5.png)

Comment: `\`users` needs to be `\`users\``

Comment: does not work anyway